# Problem with lists' dependence (python)

Tags: python, list

I'm sure this question was answered thousands time before, but English is not my native language and I am really bad at searching so I beg your pardon.
I am trying to learn python by writing a database for my job, so I met this issue. 
Simplified peace of code:

```
    x=[[0,0],[0,0]]
    y=x[0:]
    y[0][0]="1"
    print x
```

and the output:

```
    [['1', 0], [0, 0]]
```

I understand I'm missing something fundamental here, but why "x" was changed along with "y"?. All answers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `x[0:]` does not create a 'deep copy'; it is essentially copying the references to the inner arrays, or a 'shallow copy', such that setting `y[0]` or `y[1]` would not change `x`, but setting the inner array's items would.

Comment: FYI, the `copy` module has a [`deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) method that may be what OP needs. (Also `x[0:]` may be shortened to `x[:]`)

Answer (score 2):

```
y=x[0:]
```

This does copy the list x but the since the elements of x are arrays these will be copied as references. What you need is to copy each element of x. For example:

```
y = [val[:] for val in x]
```

Then changing y won't affect x.

Edit:

Another alternative that works for a wider area of cases is like it was suggested `deepcopy`. So:

```
from copy import deepcopy

y = deepcopy(x)
```

This will work for nested list and non iterable elements.

Comment: `deepcopy` is better, because this will fail if some items are not subscriptable, and if the array consists of more than two levels.

Comment: I agree that deepcopy is better but I think this answer might be better to explain why his approach didn't work. Edited my answer with that too.

Comment: @HamsteR -- strings integers, etc. can't be changed (only replaced), they're immutable. Any mutable type will work this way -- list, dict, set, bytearray, etc. Also, be careful using `deepcopy` -- see the caveats in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).